# Loop through posts of a custom-post-type (event) and create .ics (iCal) file?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, calendar

I really need your help with a feature I have never worked with so far.

I have a custom-post-type named `wr_event`. And I created this custom `WP_Query` to retrieve all posts for this post-type that are "younger" than yesterday. Fairly simple and this works like a charm.

```
function event_list_iCal() {

    $yesterday = time() - 24*60*60;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'wr_event',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // show all posts
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_value' => $yesterday,
        'meta_compare' => '>',
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    VERSION:2.0
    PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN";

    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
        $ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT
        UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "mysite.com
        DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
        DTSTART:".unixToiCal(get_event_date($post), get_event_time($post))."00Z
        DTEND:".unixToiCal(get_event_end_date($post), get_event_end_time($post))."00Z
        SUMMARY:".get_the_title($post->ID)."
        DESCRIPTION:".get_the_content($post->ID)."
        END:VEVENT";
    endforeach;

    $ical .= "END:VCALENDAR";

    header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics');
    echo $ical;
    exit;
}

function unixToiCal($uStamp = 0, $tzone = 0.0) {
    $uStampUTC = $uStamp + ($tzone * 3600);       
    $stamp  = date("Ymd\THis\Z", $uStampUTC);
    return $stamp;       
}
```

I use this function call in my `index.php` to list all "upcoming" events.

***Creating a .ics file.***

There is another feature that I'd like to have. I want to create a .ics (iCal) file on the fly with all "upcoming" events. So I guess this shoudln't be to hard as I already have the query.

Any ideas on that matter? I would really appreciate some help with this.

**Update:**

I have two more problems with the .ics Calendar file.

I have a function `get_event_date($timestamp)` that returns a timestamp of the event-date. However there is a (for me) rather complicated part in it.

There are two variables `$date[0]` and `$time[0]` that hold different formats.
The `$date[0]` holds a timestamp `1347667200` and the `$time[0]` holds a string  e.g. `14:00`. I now need to calculate the final timestamp of the "date" plus "time" to pass it along to the `unixToical()` function.

```
if ( $timestamp ) { 
            if ( !empty( $time[0]) ) {
                $time = explode(':', $time[0]);
                $hours = $time[0];
                $minutes = $time[1];
            } else { 
                //$hours = "00";
                //$minutes = "00";
            }
            $seconds = "00";
            return $date[0] + ($hours * 60)  + $minutes;
            exit;
        }
```

The part where I set `$hours` to "00" is for when there is no time set. In that case I want to time in the final .ics to be "00:00" (midnight).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here. I guess this might be the problem why when importing the calendar file to iCal only the first event is imported. (When opening the file with a text-editor all events are in there)

Comment: Solution above looks good, why not compare the format of the file generated with a one you know works and post the differences, we can then tell you what to correct.

Comment: Thank you. See my updates above. I posted the code that is generated by my functions and the .ics code that is generated when exporting a .ics file directly form iCal under my mac. You can see my actual code I'm using right now above in the question. I have functions for returning the date as a timestamp and I found a function `unixToiCal()` that should convert the timestamp to the date needed. The functions for the event-time (`get_event_time()`) are returning the time in `14:00` format. I'm not that much of a php guy so I really need your detailed help with this.

Comment: Da schau her... a Wiener.

Comment: Try using this validator: http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/ and this spec http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/ to work out what is missing or incorrect in your file. I think the method might be required for example.

Comment: Hallo @kaiser - I bin a Tiroler.

Comment: If you open Console (In Applications/Utilities), that will show you any errors iCal reports and will help you diagnose the issue. I notice you're missing END:VEVENT lines; I'm not certain if those are necessary or not, I would guess they are, but I'm not familiar enough with the ical spec to say for certain.

Comment: @MatthewBoynes - you are right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @StephenHarris Well, I have two more problems as it seems. Maybe both are caused by the same problem – the problem I have is that I don't know how to create the timestamp to pass it along to the `unixToiCal()` function. Please see my updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entirely based on [Event Organiser](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/) (a plug-in I've developed). The code is lifted almost straight from the source but with alterations. As such I've not tested the code as given.

#### Step 1: Create a feed

This is simple:

```
add_action('init','wpse63611_add_events_feed');
function wpse63611_add_events_feed(){
     add_feed('my-events','wpse63611_events_feed_output');
}
```

This adds a feed to your site: `www.site.com?feed=my-events` or `www.site.com/feed/my-events` if you have pretty permalinks. The `wpse63611_events_feed_output()` callback will output the contents of the ICAL file. But first...

#### Step 2: Alter the query

WordPress doesn't know what this feed is meant to contain. Here we use the `pre_get_posts` to tell WordPress, that for this feed we want posts of post type 'wr_event'. We could get events from a particular category, venue or between certain dates too.

By separating out the query from the output, you can have multiple feeds which use the same output function - but query different events (based on time, location, category etc).

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse63611_event_feed_query' );
function wpse63611_event_feed_query( $query ) {

     $yesterday = current_time('timestamp') - 24*60*60;
     $compare = $latest ? '>' : '<';

     if( $query->is_feed('eo-events') ){
         $query->set('post_type', 'wr_event');
         $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
         $query->set('meta_key', 'event_date');
         $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
         $query->set('order', 'ASC');
         $query->set('meta_compare', $compare);
         $query->set('meta_value', $value);
     }
}
```

#### Step 3: The contents of the ICS file

As mentioned earlier, `wpse63611_events_feed_output()` is responsible for printing the output of our feed.

```
 function wpse63611_events_feed_output(){
      //Let's give it a name;
      $filename = urlencode( 'my_events' . date('Y-m-d') . '.ics' );

      //Collect output 
      ob_start();

      // File header
      header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
      header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename );
      header('Content-type: text/calendar');
      header("Pragma: 0");
      header("Expires: 0");
?>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//<?php  get_bloginfo('name'); ?>//NONSGML Events //EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:<?php echo get_bloginfo('name');?> - Events

<?php

    // Loop through events
    if ( have_posts() ):

         $now = new DateTime();
         $datestamp =$now->format('Ymd\THis\Z');

         while( have_posts() ): the_post();
              global $post;

              $uid = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true))."@mysite.com";

              $start = unixToiCal(get_event_date($post), get_event_time($post));
              $end = unixToiCal(get_event_end_date($post), get_event_end_time($post));

              $summary = wpse63611_escape_icalText(get_the_title())
              $description = apply_filters('the_excerpt_rss',  get_the_content());
              $description = wpse63611_escape_icalText($description);

BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:<?php echo $uid;?>

DTSTAMP:<?php echo $datestamp;?>

DTSTART:<?php echo $start; ?>

DTEND:<?php echo $end; ?>

SUMMARY:<?php echo wpse63611_esc_ical_text($summary);?>

DESCRIPTION:<?php echo wpse63611_esc_ical_text($description);?>

END:VEVENT

         endwhile;

    endif;
?>
END:VCALENDAR
<?php

    //Collect output and echo 
    $eventsical = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $eventsical;
    exit();
}
```

I've used the `unixToiCal` function you've defined in your question. I've also used the following to remove anything that might upset an ICAL parser:

```
 function wpse63611_esc_ical_text( $text='' ){

    $text = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $text);
    $text = str_replace(",", "\,", $text);
    $text = str_replace(";", "\;", $text);
    $text = str_replace("\n", "\n ", $text);

    return $text;
 }
```

Comment: Hey Stephen. Thank you very much. I'm a really big step further. The file seems to be almost properly written. I updated my question with the output of the file. So the loop is correct and only the "outstanding/upcoming" events are in the calender - that is just what I want. However the file itself is still buggy. Can't be opened with any Calendar application. Do you see any lines that make the file not work?

Comment: I updated my question with my final two problems. Maybe you know how to do that? I need add a string `11:00` (time) to an existing timestamp of a date. And I need to find some way of passing a "placeholder" time like "00:00" if no time is set to an event.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

First add this functions to your theme's functions.php

```
//this will call the download function if needed
function Ical_download() {
    global $wp;
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($wp->query_vars["ical_download"])){
        event_list_iCal();
        exit();
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'Ical_download');


//this will add ical_download to the list of query vars
function ical_download_query_val() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('ical_download');
}

add_filter('init', 'ical_download_query_val');
function event_list_iCal( $latest = true ) {

    $yesterday = time() - 24*60*60;
    $compare = $latest ? '>' : '<';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'wr_event',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // show all posts
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_value' => $yesterday,
        'meta_compare' => $compare,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
";
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "example.com
DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
DTSTART:".get_event_date($post)."00Z
DTEND:".get_event_end_date($post);."00Z
SUMMARY:".$post->title."
DESCRIPTION:".$post->content."
END:VEVENT
";

    endwhile;

    $ical .= "END:VCALENDAR";

    //set correct content-type-header
    header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics');
    echo $ical;
    exit;

}
```

So just update the summery and description fields as well as the start and end times to the right format and your download link should be something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url').'?ical_download';?>">Download iCal</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with your code. It almost seems to work except for the fact that the calendar file can't be opened. So the download link seems to work fine, however the file can't be opened with iCal or any other Calendar Application.